# QGIS : How to make pie charts that depict quantity on certain coordinates/site?

Tags: qgis, scale, diagram, chart

Does anyone know how to create a map such as this one in QGIS? In short, if we have a table with list of sites with coordinates and and one column with numbers dedicated to μg /g according to which our pie chart is created as depicted on the picture?

[image: Map with pie charts wanted]

Comment: Did you read the QGIS documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=pie#diagrams-properties) ? if yes what didn't work ?

Comment: I understand that you want a piechart as a symbol... but I don't understand the map honestly. The legend is unclear... "récipients analysés" has nothing to do with + or - a quantity? Plus what means black and what is red? A piechart is normally in %?

Comment: @katagena Yes, the legend is % of "something" that has more or less than 5g at a ceratian location. How do I get to a symbol of this type as a pie chart?

Comment: If you need a specific symbol as pie chart you may try your hand at dynamic SVG creation. See these for some pointer : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380964/qgis-labels-with-html-formating, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/379437/use-text-diagram-for-labeling-in-qgis/379578#379578

Comment: Or you may try the geometry generator way : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367481/grayscale-pie-chart-in-qgis/367487#367487

Comment: Will try this out, thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Check [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#diagrams-properties). You’ll found what you need, I think!
[EDIT]: OK, I have a lot of minus... not sure why, so if someone could explain, it would be nice?!?

Comment: It was already mentioned in comments above... also I do not think it explains how to transform the usual pie-chart into the symbol seen above or am I missing something...